# Derive equation from graph

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am an M.Tech student from Manipal Institute of Technology, Manipal. I want to deduce the mathematical relationship between Forward Voltage and Forward Current of an LED from the characteristics given in the datasheet. How to derive equation from the graph?[image]

Answer (score 2):

I may be misunderstanding the main thrust of your question, but my interpretation is that you want to extract data from the graph.  My favorite tool is [DataThief](http://datathief.org/). It's very easy to use and quite robust.  You load the graph image and DataThief generates an array of ordered points (x,y).  At that point you can use whatever nonlinear curve fitting tools you desire, e.g. polynomial, log, exponential, and so on. 
My choice there is the `R` language and perhaps the tool `nls` for nonlinear fitting, but there are similar tools in any decent analysis application.

Answer (score 0):

The term you would be requesting for is for a curve fit.

There are a couple of ways to do this. A linear, or non-linear one. 
In this particular case you would berequire a non-linear. 
or specifically a quadratic one. 
Typically, you choose the model order by the number of bends you need in your line. Each increase in the exponent produces one more bend in the curved fitted line. It’s very rare to use more than a cubic term. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7oB4.png)

You would require a sample space. Which means x and y positions for the graph. You can use excel/minitab/spss/R/python/matlab to get your final curve out.

A quadratic linear model can be done by going to the option Stat > Fitted Line Plot.

There are more examples in the link I shared

[image: Example]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7oB4.png) http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/curve-fitting-with-linear-and-nonlinear-regression

Comment: It's not likely that the appropriate fit is a polynomial. Further, you haven't discussed how he's to get the data to feed that function.

Comment: I am under the impression there is sufficient data for x and y at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are models already out there for the current thru a diode as a function of its forward voltage.  Go find one, then tweak its constants to match the graph.

This is a case where a polynomial approximation is not going to work well unless you use a reasonably high order.  Note the logarithmic scale for current in the graph.  Diode current as a function of voltage is predominantly a exponential function.

Look at the graph carefully and you can see that for currents up to 100 mA or so, the graph is linear, meaning the exponential term dominates to the point you can ignore the others.  It should be easy to write the exponential for that range of current.

At higher currents, other effect become more relevant, so the equation gets more complicated.  Again, there are models out there that take all sorts of details into account.

Comment: There's no reason he has to stick with a polynomial curve fit.